# How to select every line in tkinter except of which start with a specific word in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need to select every line (not copy, so highlight all with the blue selection thing) except which start with CONTROLBAR (it will pass the lines which start with that word). Is there I way to do that, please?

Note: I am trying to that to a text widget:

```
text = Text(root, height=Window_sizeX, width=Window_sizeY, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set, font = (FontContainer, 11), wrap='none', undo=True, autoseparators=True)

text.pack()
```

The files which I want to use that code are files special to a game, the commands which need not be changed start with CONTROLBAR while others which am trying to copy and translate are just below them and in double-quotes, first, I tried to use `re` to at least extract the words between double quotes but it didn't work because those files have over 100,000 lines and by the time python extracts it all, it takes too much time. That's why I want to select them then copy with ctrl+c and paste to a translator, get the result and paste them over the selected so only the words in double quotes (strings) will be translated, commands will stay as they are.

There's one of those string files specific to the game: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vc8Ah49duA8lMJbK4bV3ZGG5W1r1n4qX/view?usp=sharing

**Edit: I forgot to say that there's also ENDs which need not be changed**

````
def opn():

    global file

    text.delete(1.0 , END)

    with open(askopenfilename() , 'r', encoding=DefaultEnco) as file:

        if file != '':

            global txt
            txt = file.read()

            text.insert(INSERT,txt)

        else:

            pass

def SelectAllQuotes():
    global txt, file
    for line in txt:
        if line.startswith(str(('"'))) and line.endswith(str(('"'))):
           text.focus()
           text.tag_add("sel", line)
           text.clipboard_clear()
           text.clipboard_append(text.selection_get())
           print('copied')

``` i made this code but it gives this error: 

```Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\SERCE\Desktop\TEST2\Shadow's Bfme Editor - Copy (2).py", line 740, in SelectAllQuotes
    text.tag_add("sel", line)
  File "C:\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3825, in tag_add
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad text index """
````

Comment: The text widget has documentation for how to search the widget, as well as how to apply formatting to ranges of characters. What have you tried? Why is available documentation not enough?

Comment: English is not my language + in most of documentations they do not detail enough in my opinion, i know the tag_add and SEL commnand but no more i have no idea to make the thing i want, also i don't know really about ranges @BryanOakley

Comment: Maybe some videos in `Text` will help?

Comment: @BryanOakley   hey, i made a code as you asked before